# Is there a cleaner way to test long list of parameters in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing

I have a function which takes a **keywords parameter, and I want to loop through parameters in a list to test whether or not the function is working accurately. However, when I give the parameters with key, value pairs such as 'name=joe,' python complains of syntax only in the list. So, I hacked a solution with encapsulating the parameters in quotes and using the exec function for calling the parameters. However, this seems hacky, and is there a better way to test functions with many test cases? Here is my code:

```
def function(**keywords):
    for key, value in keywords.items():
         print(value)
joe = 'joe'
bug='bug'
parameter_list = ('name=joe, insect=bug', 'name=joe')

# test parameters my hacky way
for parameters in parameter_list:
    # place to test function
    exec('function('+parameters+')', locals(), globals())
```

If my original design for testing this way is unpreferred, I am open to any alternatives!
Thanks!

Comment: why don't you pass a dictionary of the parameters instead?

Answer (score 1):

why don't you pass a tuple of dictionaries of arguments instead?

```
def function(**keywords):
    for key, value in keywords.items():
         print(value)

joe = "joe"
bug = "bug"  # if you want an indirection...

parameter_list = ({'name':joe, 'insect':bug}, {'name':joe})
for parameters in parameter_list:
    # place to test function
    function(**parameters)
```

Comment: I guess I could do that, but I was hoping I could test the actual parameters given. It seems that would be a lot less hacky. Thanks!